# XCUI Test fails due to MBProgressHud

Tags: ios, xcuitest

I am running a XCUI test on a view controller. Every time the view is initialize, an api call is made and an MBProgressHud is shown. My test demands to search for a button and tap on it, however I can't tap since an overlapping MBProgressHud is shown and also the api doesn't receive the response it needs to show the button. This led to failure of test.

My questions is what I am doing wrong.

1. Can we include this type of scenarios (like api calling) in our ui testing?
2. How to wait for the api call completion to continue our ui test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. We can include these scenarios in our ui testing. Here is the function we need to wait for the ui element to appear:

```
func waitForElementToAppear(_ element: XCUIElement) -> XCUIElement? {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    let expectation = XCTNSPredicateExpectation(predicate: predicate,
                                                object: element)

    let result = XCTWaiter().wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 10)
    if result == .completed {
        return element
    }

    return nil
}
```

This function will wait for api call to be completed and requires ui element to appear.

Comment: we use a similar API heavily in our automation suites. However creating the predicate and waiting for it is a heavy operation. To optimize the time taken by this API, we first check once if element.exists is true, return immediately. Otherwise go ahead with waiting for predicate. This simple change has saved us a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use and this works fine.

```
func waitForExistence(timeout: TimeInterval) -> Bool
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/2879412-waitforexistence